# awk to rename txt files using partial match in another file, appending the partial match to the txt files

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to rename all `txt` files in a directory based on a partial match to `$2` of `file`. The `txt` files in the directory are then have the `$2` string in `file` used to rename them. The `txt` files only need to have the string that matches replaced. That is the portion after the `-` remains. The `awk` below, thank you `@markp-fuso`, executes but returns the attempts I made return the original `txt` file unchanged. Thank you :).

**current directory structure**

```
123_1_000.txt
456_2_101.txt
789_3_200.txt
```

**file**

```
aaa 123_1
bbb 456_2
ccc 789_3
```

**desired directory**

```
aaa_000.txt
bbb_101.txt
ccc_200.txt
```

**awk**

```
t=$(ls *.txt) | echo $t | awk '{sub(/([_^]*:){2}/,"")}1' |  # list all txt files in directory
awk '
FNR==NR { map[$2]=$1; next }                                # store $2 from file in map array, goto next
    { split($0,a,".")                                       # split on . using txt files and read in string into [a]
      if (a[1] in map)                                      # if [a] matches map
         print "mv \"" $0 "\" \"" map[a[1]]* ".txt\""       # rename txt with map[a] string
    }
' file -                                                    # read stdin as 2nd input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, whether you use bash, or other advanced shell, that provides process substitution or you pipe and read from `-`, the following will rename the files in the current directory removing the prefix `[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]` and replacing with the `$1` value from `file` that corresponds to the prefix.

The key is to provide a relationship between the array index holding the replacement and the value of the array holding the prefix as its index. Below the `a[]` array saves the `$1` values from `file` indexed by line-number while the `b[]` array holds the prefix as index with the line-number stored as its value (you can use a counter if you like, e.g. `++n`).

The `match()` command is used to create the `c[]` array which holds the prefix taken from the current filename and if the prefix exists in the `b[]` array the filename is saved and the new filename is created by `sub()` on `$1` and the is moved to the new filename using the `system()` command with the command string built by concatenation in `cmd`.

```bash
awk '
  FNR==NR {       # reading from file
    a[NR] = $1    # save $1 to array indexed by NR
    b[$2] = NR    # save $2 as index to array with NR as value
  }
  NR>FNR {        # handling filenames
    match($1,/^[[:digit:]]+_[[:digit:]]+/,c)  # save up to last _ in c array
    if (c[0] in b) {              # if prefix present in b array
      fname=$1                    # save current filename
      sub(c[0], a[b[c[0]]], $1)   # sub a array with prefix for new filename
      cmd="mv "fname" "$1         # create move command string
      system(cmd)                 # move current to new filename
    }
  }
' file <(ls -1 *.txt)
```

(**note:** the redirected command substitution `<(ls -1 *.txt)` is used to provide the filenames. If your shell does not provide that capability, then pipe the filenames to the command and add `-` as a filename causing awk to read `stdin` -- as you have done)

**Example Results**

With your original filenames in the present directory and the contents in `file`, e.g.

```
$ cat file
aaa 123_1
bbb 456_2
ccc 789_3
```

the result of the above is:

```
$ ll
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  6 16:09 aaa_000.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  6 16:09 bbb_101.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david    0 Jan  6 16:09 ccc_200.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   30 Jan  6 16:09 file
```

Note, if you don't care about matching `[[:digit:]]` you can remove the prefix with `/^[^_]+_[^_]+/` to match anything in the prefix up to the second `'_'`.

Comment: Thank you very much for help and the explanations, they were very helpful :)

Comment: You are very welcome! Good luck with your scripting!